# Can't beforeCreate work same as asyncData in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When I was learning Nuxt.js I found that `asyncData` wait for the  data to be loaded so that it can create the component.
Then even `beforeCreate` is executed before the component is created.
My problem is can't they work the same.

Comment: beforeCreate isn't supposed to work like that in Vue, it doesn't wait for anything and proceeds to created instantly. This is the reason why additional asyncData method was introduced in Nuxt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `beforeCreate` is called synchronously immediately after the instance has been initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup.

The difference to `asyncData` is that `beforeCreate` happens in your browser and `asyncData` happens on the server side.

That means in `asyncData` you cant access things like `localStorage`, `fetch()` or `document` because it is executed on the server side.

But `asyncData` provides an argument called `context`.

The context is kinda special, it allows you to access for example your Vuex store witch is on client side usually: https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/

```
asyncData(context){
   console.log(context.store); //you need to check your server console NOT! your browser console
}
```

You will see often that peopole use ES6 deustructuring to access the property:

```
asyncData({ store }){
       console.log(store); //you need to check your server console NOT! your browser console
    }
```

ofcorse you can destructure more properties:

```
asyncData({ store, redirect, query, params }){
       console.log(store); //you need to check your server console NOT! your browser console
    }
```